# 'yield from' alternative for async def function

Tags: python, python-asyncio, coroutine, iterable

In a class that is almost 100% async I need to execute some code (that is currently a coroutine) in a synchronous (sequential) way.
So I created this function:

```
@asyncio.coroutine
def execute_sequential(self, doo):
    for key in doo:
        yield from self.fetch_one_fin_instr_hist_data(doo[key])
```

That I execute it with these commands:

```
tasks = [self.execute_sequential(doo)]
await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
```

The *fetch_one_fin_instr_hist_data* must be a coroutine since it is called by an async function.
It has the following signature:

```
async def fetch_one_fin_instr_hist_data(self, obj):
```

Everything works fine.
Unfortunately the `@asyncio.coroutine` is deprecated, so I should replace it with the `async def` keywords.
The `yield from` is not supported by `async def`.

I have tried the following:

```
async def execute_sequential(self, doo):
    for key in doo:
        for obj in self.fetch_one_fin_instr_hist_data(doo[key]):
            yield obj
```

but at the line

```
for obj in self.fetch_one_fin_instr_hist_data(doo[key]):
```

I get the error:

*Expected type 'collections.Iterable', got 'Coroutine[Any, Any, None]' instead*

Is there a way to convert a coroutine to an iterable?
Or better, what could be an alternative for *yield from* in this case?

Comment: `yield from` has been replaced with `await` in that context.

Comment: “ fetch_one_fin_instr_hist_data must be a coroutine since it is called by an async function” does it do anything asynchronous? If not, it doesn’t need to be a coroutine.

Comment: ok, simply replacing `yield from` with `await` works! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

While `yield from` is still valid for creating a generator, this particular has been replaced by the `await` keyword.

```
@asyncio.coroutine
def execute_sequential(self, doo):
    for key in doo:
        yield from self.fetch_one_fin_instr_hist_data(doo[key])
```

should now be

```
async def execute_sequential(self, doo):
    for key in doo:
        await self.fetch_one_fin_instr_hist_data(doo[key])
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments by dirn, `yield` was replaced with `await`:

```
async def execute_sequential(self, doo):
    for key in doo:
        for obj in self.fetch_one_fin_instr_hist_data(doo[key]):
            await obj
```